# .htaccess redirect incorrectly adds index.php to my URL

Tags: angular, .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html
# to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

this file is located in a folder: example.com/foo/.htaccess

There is an index.html file in that folder which is an angular project.

When I visit the page without www or https the redirect redirects me to https://www.example.com/foo/index.php.

I dont want this, and I dont see why it is adding index.php to the URL.

I have tried adding `DirectoryIndex index.html` to the file, but this breaks all redirects from working at all.

Comment: It is not that dynamic configuration file you posted which makes the redirection to the `index.php` file. It might be your http servers index settings or some server side scripting solution.

Comment: @arkascha Ive looked through out CPanel and the higher level .htaccess file. I cant see anything that would set index.php as the default file to load

Comment: What is the configuration of the `DirectoryIndex` setting of the apache http server? And what application logic do you have on the server side?